# String Replace turn result to integers python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
line = ['R2', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R10', 'R12', 'R13', 'R15', 'R18', 'R20', 'R21', 'R22', 'R23', 'R24', 'R26', 'R30', 'R31', 'R32', 'R33', 'R34', 'R35', 'R36', 'R37', 'R38', 'R44', 'R45', 'R46', 'R47', 'R48', 'R53', 'R55', 'R56', 'R63', 'R66', 'R68', 'R69', 'R70', 'R74', 'R78', 'R80', 'R81', 'R82', 'R83', 'R84', 'R90', 'R91', 'R92', 'R97', 'R98', 'R99', 'R100', 'R101', 'R102', 'R103', 'R108', 'R109', 'R111', 'R115', 'R116', 'R117', 'R118', 'R120', 'R121', 'R123', 'R124', 'R126', 'R130', 'R131', 'R132', 'R136', 'R138', 'R141', 'R142', 'R151', 'R152', 'R153', 'R154', 'R155', 'R156', 'R158', 'R160', 'R161', 'R163', 'R164', 'R167', 'R169', 'R171', 'R172', 'R177', 'R178', 'R179', 'R180', 'R181', 'R182', 'R183', 'R184', 'R186', 'R190', 'R192', 'R195', 'R196', 'R199', 'R201', 'R203', 'R204', 'R205', 'R206', 'R207', 'R209', 'R210', 'R211', 'R213', 'R214', 'R215', 'R216', 'R217', 'R223', 'R225', 'R227', 'R228', 'R229', 'R231', 'R233', 'R237', 'R238', 'R239', 'R240', 'R245', 'R246', 'R247', 'R248', 'R249', 'R250', 'R252', 'R253', 'R254', 'R255', 'R257', 'R258', 'R265', 'R266', 'R267', 'R268', 'R270', 'R271', 'R273', 'R275', 'R276', 'R277', 'R279', 'R280', 'R281', 'R284', 'R287', 'R290', 'R291', 'R292', 'R293', 'R294', 'R296', 'R299', 'R300', 'R301', 'R303', 'R304', 'R305', 'R306', 'R307', 'R308', 'R309', 'R310', 'R312', 'R313', 'R314', 'R315', 'R317', 'R320', 'R321', 'R323', 'R325', 'R327', 'R329', 'R330', 'R331', 'R334', 'R335', 'R336', 'R339', 'R340', 'R341', 'R343', 'R344', 'R345', 'R347', 'R349', 'R350', 'R352', 'R354', 'R356', 'R358', 'R359', 'R360', 'R361', 'R362', 'R363', 'R365', 'R367', 'R372', 'R373', 'R376', 'R378', 'R379', 'R381', 'R384', 'R386', 'R388', 'R393', 'R397', 'R398', 'R399', 'R401', 'R402', 'R403', 'R405', 'R406', 'R407', 'R410', 'R411', 'R413', 'R414', 'R416', 'R419', 'R420', 'R421', 'R422', 'R427', 'R430', 'R433', 'R434', 'R435', 'R438', 'R439', 'R443', 'R444', 'R445', 'R453', 'R454', 'R455', 'R456', 'R458', 'R459', 'R460', 'R461', 'R462', 'R463', 'R464', 'R466', 'R467', 'R468', 'R469', 'R470', 'R473', 'R475', 'R476', 'R478', 'R481', 'R482', 'R483', 'R485', 'R487', 'R488', 'R489', 'R490', 'R492', 'R494', 'R496', 'R497', 'R499', 'R500', 'R502', 'R503', 'R506', 'R508', 'R509', 'R511', 'R512', 'R516', 'R517', 'R519', 'R520', 'R528', 'R530', 'R532', 'R537', 'R539', 'R540', 'R541', 'R542', 'R544', 'R545', 'R547', 'R549', 'R550', 'R552', 'R555', 'R558', 'R560', 'R561', 'R562', 'R563', 'R564', 'R565', 'R566', 'R568', 'R571', 'R572', 'R573', 'R574', 'R576', 'R579', 'R581', 'R583', 'R584', 'R585', 'R586', 'R588', 'R590', 'R592', 'R593', 'R595', 'R597', 'R598', 'R600', 'R601', 'R606', 'R607', 'R609', 'R610', 'R612', 'R613', 'R614', 'R615', 'R617', 'R618', 'R619', 'R620', 'R622', 'R624', 'R625', 'R626', 'R627', 'R628', 'R629', 'R630', 'R631', 'R632', 'R633', 'R634', 'R635', 'R636', 'R638', 'R642', 'R644', 'R645', 'R646', 'R647', 'R648', 'R649', 'R650', 'R652', 'R654', 'R657', 'R658', 'R660', 'R662', 'R668', 'R669', 'R671', 'R672', 'R673', 'R674', 'R676', 'R677', 'R678', 'R683', 'R684', 'R686', 'R689', 'R691', 'R693', 'R694', 'R696', 'R697', 'R698', 'R700', 'R701', 'R704', 'R706', 'R707', 'R710', 'R712', 'R713', 'R715', 'R716', 'R718', 'R719', 'R721', 'R724', 'R725', 'R728', 'R729', 'R730', 'R731', 'R733', 'R734', 'R737', 'R738', 'R739', 'R740', 'R743', 'R744', 'R745', 'R747', 'R748', 'R751', 'R755', 'R756', 'R757', 'R758', 'R759', 'R761', 'R762', 'R763', 'R767', 'R768', 'R770', 'R773', 'R774', 'R775', 'R776', 'R777', 'R779', 'R783', 'R785', 'R786', 'R789', 'R791', 'R795', 'R796', 'R797', 'R798', 'R800', 'R801', 'R802', 'R804', 'R805', 'R806', 'R808', 'R818', 'R819', 'R820', 'R822', 'R824', 'R826', 'R827', 'R829', 'R830', 'R831', 'R833', 'R835', 'R836', 'R838', 'R840', 'R841', 'R843', 'R844', 'R845', 'R847', 'R848', 'R849', 'R850', 'R851', 'R852', 'R853', 'R855', 'R858', 'R859', 'R860', 'R862', 'R863', 'R865', 'R867', 'R868', 'R869', 'R870', 'R874', 'R875', 'R876', 'R880', 'R881', 'R882', 'R884', 'R885', 'R886', 'R889', 'R891', 'R892', 'R893', 'R894', 'R895', 'R897', 'R900', 'R906', 'R908', 'R909', 'R911', 'R912', 'R914', 'R917', 'R918', 'R921', 'R922', 'R924', 'R925', 'R926', 'R927', 'R928', 'R929', 'R930', 'R932', 'R935', 'R937', 'R943', 'R944', 'R945', 'R946', 'R947', 'R948', 'R949', 'R951', 'R952', 'R953', 'R956', 'R957', 'R958', 'R959', 'R961', 'R964', 'R965', 'R966', 'R967', 'R968', 'R969', 'R971', 'R972', 'R974', 'R975', 'R976', 'R979', 'R981', 'R982', 'R983', 'R986', 'R987', 'R988', 'R990', 'R993', 'R994', 'R997']

ref = str(line).replace("R","")
print(ref)
```

it prints `('2', '5', '6', '7', '10', '12', '13', '15', '18', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '26', '30', '31', '32', '33', ......` and so on

Would like to turn to `integers(2,5,6,7,10,12,13,15,18...` and so on.  I have tried but no good results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list comprehension

```
line = [int(l.replace("R", "")) for l in line]
```

If "R" is always the first character, you can also do:

```
line = [int(l[1:]) for l in line]
```

Per the data provided, both solution above will work solve the original question, if you may have invalid data, for example `R32R` the above will fail and raise a `ValueError` exception.

To prevent this you can discard any value that are not an integer by using:

```
item.isnumeric()
line = [int(l[1:]) for l in line if l[1:].isnumeric()]
```

You can also achieve the same with a regex expression

```
re.search('\d+', line[0]).group(0)
line = [int(re.search('\d+', l).group(0)) for l in line if re.search('\d+', l) is not None]
```

You will need the following import:

```
import re
```

Comment: This works provided the replaced value is all numeric values. It will fail if there is a string in it.

Comment: `line = [int(x[1:]) for x in line if x[1:].isnumeric()]` will be better and protects from risk of a number being non-numeric

Comment: @JoeFerndz That is correct, data was provided and no indication this would be the case. You can add an ```if isinstance(l[1:], int)``` condition in the list comprehension but the OP's question/data provided suggest this is not needed. Else what do we do in such case, discard or another action..

Comment: instance wont work as the value will still be string. you need to check for isnumeric

Comment: upvoted for the list comprehension solution.

Comment: And using replace you are assuming it is always a R. Thanks for the upvote, I will add the check for ```isnumeric```. OP can decide what to do after all.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I am an electronics engineer and I am trying to shorten the list coming out of our database right now with hyphens.  Like R1-R7 instead of explicitly written out. Most of the component designators have a character in front of the integer like R, C, L, U, DS, etc.  This helps a lot.  I am going to try and figure out the bigger challenge from here.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: The second solution will help with any components that only have one letter, but as soon as you have multiple letters it won't help much. At this point you best solution is to use a regex expression. See the updated answer with regex. Not sure I follow the ```R1-R7```, if this is in the output, my suggestion will be to loop through the list, split each items and use the regex. Building a new list with each value obtain. Let me know if you need more help with that. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if that helped you out.